# How can I get 100% completion in Mafia 2?

Tags: mafia-2

I've completed Mafia 2, but it tells me that I've completed only 75%. How do I complete the remaining 25%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with the story mode, there are many collectibles such as Playboy Magazines and Wanted Posters. You will have to collect these as well if you want 100% completion.

A guide to all the collectibles can be found [HERE](http://guides.ign.com/guides/957841/).